# Are there any languages that understand the characters ≥ and ≤?

Tags: operators, logical-operators

This is merely a question of curiosity; while we have characters in unicode to represent ≥ and ≤ instead of using >= and <=, I can't seem to find a programming language that supports it.

Are any known to exist?

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted? This is a question that fits within the qualities outlined in the FAQ. It is a question that will help better understand programming, and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else. It is not a duplicate, nor is it off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would this be used? `>=` is much easier to type then `≥`. In Casio basic, `≥` is used and `>=` does not work. However, on a Casio calculator, it is just as easy to type `≥` as it is to type `>`.

Comment: As I said, this is merely out of curiosity. That's right though, Casio and TI do use the ≥ operators. +1